# Is Solr phrase slop order dependent or not?

Tags: solr, lucene

Using the default example docs and schema that comes with Solr 4.7.0 (the one with ipods etc.).

A query with phrase slop such as:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?wt=json&q=features:%22car%20white%22~4&fl=id,features&omitHeader=true
```

Gives me 2 matching documents:

```
{
  "response":{"numFound":2,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"F8V7067-APL-KIT",
        "features":["car power adapter, white"]},
      {
        "id":"IW-02",
        "features":["car power adapter for iPod, white"]}]
  }}
```

If I change from "car white" to "white car" using the same slop value of 4 I get only the first document in the result.
Looking at the explain in browse, for the document returned in the both queries it says:

```
(MATCH) weight(features:"white car"~4 in 3)
```

For the other document, in the first case is says `..."car white"~4 in 4)` but changing the order to "white car" does not match the document.

This seems to imply that it's "somewhat" order dependent... but not really?  Can anyone explain what is going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you swap those words, the edit distance increases.  A swap, essentially, adds 2 to the edit distance (since the first edit moves the words on top of one another).

with the query "car white" you have

- "car power adapter, white" - distance = 2 (2 extra words)
- "car power adapter for iPod, white" - distance = 4 (4 extra words)

with "white car" you have:

- "car power adapter, white" - distance = 4 (1 swap, 2 extra words)
- "car power adapter for iPod, white" - distance = 6 (1 swap, 4 extra words)

Since slop is set to 4 in your query, the last result has too high an edit distance, and does not appear.  [`PhraseQuery.setSlop()`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/PhraseQuery.html#setSlop%28int%29) documents the behavior of phrase slop, for further reading.

Comment: excellent answer, thank you, and thanks for the link to the documentation.